# URL Rewriting in codeigniter rewrite the URL for next page after login

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm having a hardtime on this part. Well I created a login page using codeigniter wherein the whole path would be `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php` will be rewritten into `http://localhost/login` using .htaccess. Well it works just fine but the problem is after I made a successful login and the page redirects to next page using redirect('next_page'); since the URL would be `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/next_page` instead of `http://localhost/next_page`. I also created a rewriterule for that part :

```
RewriteRule ^events$ /CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/events [L,NC]
```

and whenever I key in the `http://localhost/next_page` in the addressbar the page would appear just fine (since I haven't applied any rules on login and on this page.) I also tried using redirect('http://localhost/events'); this also works just fine but still I know this is not the real solution for this. Oh by the way my .htaccess exists on the www folder of wampserver. Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your domain ROOT folder should be the codeigniter folder

forexample

```
c:/www/codeigniter_2.1.3/
```

just move the files from the codeigniter_2.1.3 to your root folder OR make the codeigniter folder ROOT.

Then use just normal .htaccess rewrite as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And use the Codeigniter ROUTER to make your pages as you want them

example:

```
$route['login'] = 'welcome/login';
```

Will set `http://localhost/login` page to be loaded from the Welcome controler Login function.
You can set $routes at your routes.php in the config folder.

P.S> If you want not to see index.php on each page check your Config/config.php for the index_page and make it blank.

Comment: So we meet again Svetlio haha! well for my previous question I'm still figuring it out. Well for this one I just ask one thing. what does this part do? RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css) Well, I can't understand why it contains images and robots on the text and I only know the basics of the URL rewriting. hope you can explain it to me more further. Anyway your answer makes sense to me about moving the folder. Thanks for that.

Comment: The line with the images robots txt is not required ;)
Its about such file types as txt and css

How ever the other lines are the important !

Comment: I see, applied it and removed my form target for login page and well success for the error handling in  wrong credentials. Now another question about this part redirect('http://localhost/events'); after a successful login my page redirects exactly on what I wanted it to be. but I know for myself that this is a wrong approach. how should I solve this part for me not to use exact URL location when redirecting?

Comment: solved the problem by getting the base path first then concatinating it so that it would be more flexible. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to add virtual host to your localhost. here is one [step by step explanation on how to do that](http://www.trailheadinteractive.com/creating_multiple_virtual_sites_a_single_apache_install_windows_xp).

now all you have to do is create an `.htaccess` file inside your `CodeIgniter_2.1.3` folder that will remove only the `index.php` in the url.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I think it answers more than what I need. I appreciate it though. Thanks again.